# Need help in showing the Location of Caller

Tags: android

I am developing an android app that shows the location of the caller when an incoming call come on incoming call screen. I am succesfully fetching the location from my algorithm but I am not able to display it on Deafult Incoming Screen.

If i use A toast then it just appears for 1 or 2seconds, I want ihe information shoulkd appear till the call picked.

What should I use Toast, Notification or something , and how to do that.

In short how can I show something on Incoming Call Screen till the call picked up

Comment: What is the code where you are trying to show it with in your call information screen? This will help us and also you!

Comment: I am using a incoming call reciever (Class) which extends Broadcast reciver and in onRecieve() method i am trying to show the information.

Comment: But how do you try to show the information? That piece of code will give us insight in your problem and maybe somebody can help you then.